# Creating shortest path up surface?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, slope, distance-matrix

I have X,Y,Z points that I can create a surface in arc with. I wanted to know if there is a tool that would show me the shortest path up this surface to the highest point. This could be based off of contours or just the values of the Z(depth) points perhaps. 
So the main objective is the shortest path from an actual point location that lies on the XYZ surface to the steepest point on the surface and shortest path.
Does arc have a tool that will create this path as a line or something like this?

Comment: It is called cost path, use your elevation raster as cost surface and point as destination

Comment: Ok. I have one point for a location and I created a surface using nearest neighbor. Your saying if I have this then I would use the cost path tool? Im looking at the Cost path tool and it requires more inputs, Input raster, input cost distance raster and input cost backlink raster. Is there a way to create the shortest path from the point that I have and up the surface that I created?

Comment: Also, Im not sure if this is worded right, I  have a point and a surface, the surface has elevation. I don't have a destination point., I want to find the shortest path up the surface, not to a destination point, but to the steepest tallest point on the surface, the shortest route up the surface

Comment: Steepest tallest point is nonsense. Slope at the peak is 0. Define where to you want to travel and this will become your destination point. Using elevation and this point you can calculate back link. Unless you are trying to travel to nearest ridge. Note that highest point of your original is a peak

Comment: Ill look into the process. I wanted to know for an example, I have a starting point and want to know which path up my contoured surface is the shortest quickest path. I thought somehow based off of the contour(surface) values it could do this. I could locate the destination by hand, as in following the contours, but on a complex surface I thought there would be a different way. So I am looking for the destination point, I don't have that. I didn't know about the tools you mentioned so I can look into this now, thank you